# Is there a way to make Openbox behave like the Compiz Grid plugin?

Tags: compiz, lubuntu, openbox

I've been happily using Compiz with the Grid plugin on Ubuntu 10.04 on my Mini Inspiron netbook. However, due to battery life issues, I'm considering downgrading to a lighter Ubuntu derivative, and would like to try Lubuntu, which uses the Openbox window manager. I'm wondering, is there any way to make Openbox behave a bit more like a tiling window manager, in a manner similar to the Compiz Grid plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [PyTile](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pytile/):

> PyTile automatically tiles all windows. It allows tiling of an arbitrary number of windows in up to 9 columns.