# How do I arrange windows with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: compiz, lubuntu

I have been testing with Lubuntu and have found it really pleasant.  However, I cannot find an answer for one essential (for me) feature: being able to arrange windows with keyboard shortcuts.

In Ubuntu this is done with the "Grid" plugin in "compizconfig-settings-manager". Unity uses this as well for window arranging.

I am not interested in the "drag to the left to take up 1/2 the screen", but rather just the "hit some key combo" to put the active window to the left 1/2 of the screen, for example.

I found this entry in "askubuntu" asking a very similar question:

[Is there a way to make Openbox behave like the Compiz Grid plugin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15198/is-there-a-way-to-make-openbox-behave-like-the-compiz-grid-plugin)

But it seems the "answer to this question", namely pyTile (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pytile/), doesn't do what I would like it to do.  I don't want to tile all current windows, I want to resize one window at a time as I specify (left, right, top, center, bottom, 1/2, 2/3, 1/3, etc.). And I would prefer to do so with the keyboard.

I think it possible to install compiz in Lubuntu, but this seems like "overkill" for this one feature (Grid keyboard shortcuts).  Any help out there?  It would REALLY MAKE MY DAY!!!

Comment: sounds like you want to use a tiling manager specifically made for this type of feature - for example http://xmonad.org/documentation.html

Comment: you can try [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Awesome_3_configuration) its very light and will fit lubuntu as well

Comment: In my quick evaluation, both xmonad and awesome are both looking to take a fair amount of setup / tweaking to get to work as I would like them to.  Maybe sometime I'll check them out. For now, the answer below for PyWO does exactly what I need and it very simple to use and setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LewisTM over on ubuntuforums.org gave a great reply that solves all my problems:

> If you want to keep your window
>   manager and emulate the grid fucntionality, you can try [PyWO - Python Window Organizer](http://code.google.com/p/pywo/). It can be controlled with the keyboard.
>
> Cheers!

I had first tried installing compiz, but it made all sorts of problems as the lxde panel sort of had problems, keyboard shortcuts (like ctrl alt t) stopped working, etc. It really caused issues.

This python script does everything I need it to! Highly recommended.

Comment: This would be a good answer if you can describe how to install, configure and use this...

Comment: I would prefer to not re-document as the PyWO site that I link does a good job of explaining how it works.

Comment: I will add that it is "installed" by simply adding the script to a "Startup Application" launcher.  Again, the site linked above has the information if someone wants to consider it.  I do see that there has not been active development since Aug 2010 so it may be "dead".